# Interact with a windows-based (GUI) application via Java code?

Tags: java, selenium, awtrobot

**Background:**

We have been working on automation-based testing in our application. And we are using Selenium for testing web-based applications.

**Question:**

Now, we have a requirement "on click of a **button**" it opens **"PuTTY.exe".**

To complete our end-to-end testing, we have to enter a username and password in an opened window.
And make sure we are able to connect to the host.

Is there a way we can interact with the other application (other than the browser)?

Comment: Not sure what your exact needs are, and how connected with the tested application your utility needs to be, but perhaps AutoIt would fill your needs.

Comment: I have used sikuli in the past for interacting with content outside of the browser. It may be worth investigating.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As I mentioned, Clicking on a button on web page, will open putty.exe thru Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\putty.exe"); Now thru code, I want to type username/password in the opened putty window. Let me know if you understand my problem.

Comment: If you automate your test, you will not type you username/password yourself, here http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-general-opts you can see that you can add some parameters to launch a connection (but not sure how you will check if this is ok)

Comment: x('//div/div/div/h3/text()').forEach(function(el){console.log(el)})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) to handle desktop-based windows using Java and Selenium.

Also see [the AutoIt documentation page](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you:

```
public class Runtime{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\putty.exe username password");
    }
}
```

If your application support variable args, the above code is applicable.

Comment: Putty has some doc, there is parameter that can be set, you need -l -P -pw ... or using a session -load

Comment: What is this `varargs` you speak of? Do you have a reference? Respond by editing your answer, not here in comments (if appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

[AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) sounds like a good solution.

It can interact with Windows forms directly from your code. You'll have to download its own standalone executable, and add its references to your project. Once everything is set, you'll need to map the elements you want to interact with in your application (the AutoIt executable can help you with that), and will be able to code the desired interactions.

[This tutorial](http://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html) covers up pretty much everything you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the credentials class of Java to enter username and password in the windows popup. To click on the button, you can use the Java robot class.

Comment: Can you add some references (links) to the mentioned Java classes? (As I don't think you can't use links yet, perhaps some unambigous Google search terms and/or some domains where they are, etc.)